# Training hyperparameters for multidimensional Gaussian process regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is a simple working implementation of a code where I use Gaussian process regression (GPR) in Python's scikit-learn with 2-dimensional inputs (i.e grid over `x1` and `x2`) and 1-dimensional outputs (`y`).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor 
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#  Example independent variable (observations)
X = np.array([[0.,0.], [1.,0.], [2.,0.], [3.,0.], [4.,0.], 
                [5.,0.], [6.,0.], [7.,0.], [8.,0.], [9.,0.], [10.,0.], 
                [11.,0.], [12.,0.], [13.,0.], [14.,0.],
                [0.,1.], [1.,1.], [2.,1.], [3.,1.], [4.,1.], 
                [5.,1.], [6.,1.], [7.,1.], [8.,1.], [9.,1.], [10.,1.], 
                [11.,1.], [12.,1.], [13.,1.], [14.,1.],
                [0.,2.], [1.,2.], [2.,2.], [3.,2.], [4.,2.], 
                [5.,2.], [6.,2.], [7.,2.], [8.,2.], [9.,2.], [10.,2.], 
                [11.,2.], [12.,2.], [13.,2.], [14.,2.]])#.T

# Example dependent variable (observations) - noiseless case 
y = np.array([4.0, 3.98, 4.01, 3.95, 3.9, 3.84,3.8,
              3.73, 2.7, 1.64, 0.62, 0.59, 0.3, 
              0.1, 0.1,
            4.4, 3.9, 4.05, 3.9, 3.5, 3.4,3.3,
              3.23, 2.6, 1.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.32, 
              0.05, 0.02,
            4.0, 3.86, 3.88, 3.76, 3.6, 3.4,3.2,
              3.13, 2.5, 1.6, 0.55, 0.51, 0.23, 
              0.11, 0.01]) 

x1 = np.linspace(0, 14, 20)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 100) 

i = 0 
inputs_x = []
while i < len(x1):
    j = 0
    while j < len(x2):
        inputs_x.append([x1[i],x2[j]])
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
inputs_x_array = np.array(inputs_x) 

# Instantiate a Gaussian Process model
kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF((1e-2, 1e2), (1e-2, 1e2))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=20)

gp.fit(X, y.reshape(-1,1)) #removing reshape results in a different error

y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(inputs_x_array, return_std=True)
```

It works, but when defining the kernel, how can I ensure I set different hyperparameters (e.g. different scale lengths) for my different inputs (i.e. `x1` and `x2`)? In the example above, the standard kernel used is a radial basis function (RBF) which appears to have a single length scale despite two input dimensions. But how could this kernel (or a custom kernel, e.g. hyperbolic tangent) be trained to account for different hyperparameters for the different input dimensions?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need anisotropic kernels, which are only supported by a few kernels in sklearn for the moment. RBF is such an example where you can give a list as input for the `length_scale` parameter. For example, `RBF(length_scale = [1, 10], length_scale_bounds=(1e-5, 1e5))` is perfectly valid, where 1 holds for `x1` and 10 holds for `x2`.

Most kernels in sklearn however are isotropic, where the anisotropic case is -currently- not supported. If you want more freedom, I suggest you take a look at other packages (like GPy) or you can always try to implement your own anisotropic kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I've been searching for templates to implement custom anisotropic kernels (e.g. tanh) for GPR in scikit-learn, which is the primary focus of the question and of wide applicability. I'm still in the process of trying to write a general solution helpful for everyone, although a working example would fully answer the question.

Comment: @Mathews24, I'll try to give it a go, but I have no experience whatsoever in implementing an anisotropic kernel in sklearn. Will give it a shot though.

Comment: @Mathews24, still no implementation, however, I've found 'George' to be an extremely helpful package, especially for anisotropic kernels. It's also a lot faster than sklearn.

Comment: I also came across additional custom kernels [here](https://github.com/jmetzen/gp_extras/tree/0d0d22fc74825fd163143753e9de048cc68f7abf) for sklearn which provide some nice capability (e.g. heteroscedasticity). Still trying to learn how to specify input dimension (as in George) and encode a custom kernel (i.e. hyperbolic tangent).

Comment: Just to add on to your present answer since it's seemingly almost there: how could the `RBF` kernel be implemented such that it only accounts for `x1`, and a different kernel (e.g. Matern), only accounts for `x2` in the above code? The resulting covariance is a combination of stationary kernels (i.e. `k[x1,x1',x2,x2'] = RBF[x1,x1']*Matern[x2,x2']`), where the individual kernels themselves only act on one dimension.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in sklearn to have anisotropic kernels which only work in *one* dimension. You could however adjust the length_scale, because generally speaking, a larger lengthscale means that the learnt function varies less in that direction, which is another way of saying that that feature is irrelevant for the learnt function. So you can simply take a very large value for the dimension that's not relevant to the kernel.

Comment: Also, in George this is a bit more straightforward, for example ExpSquaredKernel([5, 10.0], ndim=4, axes=[2,3]) here means that the data consists of 4 dimensions, but we only want this RBF kernel to account for the third and fourth dimension (this is the axes parameter), with length_scales of respectively 5 and 10.

Comment: I agree with the above and I've given you the first bounty for all the help. I do still think clear step-by-step instructions in sklearn to implement custom (e.g. non-stationary) anisotropic kernels is lacking to fully answer the original problem, so it is still open.

Comment: @Mathews24, thanks for the recognition. 
I'm trying to implement it myself in sklearn, but given that I'm not an expert in programming code, it can take some time. If I ever make some progress on this subject, I'll let you know.